# Dart. Idea. How to prevent formatting from merging into single line

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter, dart

I'm trying to set new formatting for me. Because of this problem.

*Before auto format.*

[image]

*After auto format.*
[image]

I checked Idea Settings. But seems there are not too many settings for Dart. I have removed all the setting with line merging. But above issue still exist. For example. This setting, which should work, but it doesn't.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can't sadly

Comment: And to elaborate, the Dart Style Guide is highly opinionated, and `dartfmt` follows it precisely.  This is to ensure that extraneous git changes don't show up when code is checked in.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz But there is should be way to configure it for your. As I mentioned in the question.

Comment: you can refer this formatting rules.
https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/Formatting-Rules

Comment: @Alfaizkhan Did you read the question?

Answer (score 1):

End each line you don't want to be affected by formatting with "//":

```dart
[1, 2, 3]
      .map((a) => 0) //
      .map((a) => 1); //
var x = [ 
  0, 1, 2, //
  3, 4, 5 //
];
```

Comment: this works sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too

My solution is "Select the range I want to auto format and click Ctrl+Alt+L"...

I have given up auto format all...

Comment: Unfortunately, It is not a solution.